# Show that for $\alpha \geq 3$, the class $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ in Borel Hierachy is not closed under arbitrary union

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, borel-sets

Suppose $X$ is a metrizable space. Define $\Sigma_1^0$ to be the set of open sets in $X$ and $\prod_1^0$ to be the set of closed sets in $X$.

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223865/additive-class-is-closed-under-arbitrary-union), I asked whether the class $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ closed under arbitrary union. By Pedro's answer, we know the answer is negative. But he did not provide a proof for a general $\alpha$, instead he provided a proof for $\alpha =2.$

I am wondering how would one prove that the class $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ is not closed under arbitrary union.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer in general depends on $X$. For instance, if we take $X$ to be the metric space with only one point, then each $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ class *is* closed under arbitrary union. More generally, in any discrete metric space every set is $\Sigma^0_1$, so each $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ class is closed under arbitrary unions.

However, as long as $X$ is sufficiently "rich" (say, $X$ is a perfect Polish space like $\mathbb{R}$),  then for $\alpha>1$ the $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ sets are not closed under arbitrary union. This is because every singleton is $\Sigma^0_2$, so *every* subset of $X$ is a union of $\Sigma^0_2$ sets. More generally, for any $\alpha>1$, every subset of $X$ is a union of $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ sets. So for a given $\alpha$, there are exactly two possibilities:

- Every subset of $X$ is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$.

OR

- The class of $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ sets is not closed under arbitrary unions.

So if we want to show that the second possibility *does* hold, it's enough to show that the first possibility *doesn't* hold. And the easiest way to do this is a cardinality argument. For instance, take $X=\mathbb{R}$. Then (exercise) for each countable ordinal $\alpha$, there are only continuum-many $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ sets; but there are more than continuum-many subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I understand your reasoning. How do we know that there are only continuum-many $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ sets? I know that there are $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ many subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @Idonknow Transfinite induction. (i) There are only continuum many $\Sigma^0_1$ sets. (ii) At successor levels, we take countably unions of things at lower levels, of which there are only continuum many; the set of countable subsets of a size-continuum set has size continuum. (iii) At limit levels, *since we're only looking at $\alpha<\omega_1$*, we're taking a countable union of size-continuum sets.

Comment: Maybe I miss out something, does your 'continuum' mean uncountable?

Comment: By Cantor's Theorem, we know that power set of $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality greater than $\mathbb{R}.$ Continuum refers to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Idonknow Yes, "continuum" doesn't just mean "uncountable," but rather "size *exactly* that of $\mathbb{R}$."